# How does RIPEMD160 pad the message?

Tags: algorithm-design, padding, ripemd

For RIPEMD hashing algorithm on hardware
I am not exactly getting how padding works

So as per my understanding padding will work like explained below:

For ripemd 160 message should be multiple of 512 bits. So, along with message to make it 512 bits, after message we pad 1 following zeros. Last 64 bits of 512 block are reserved for length of the message.

Suppose message is `a` which I have to send it for hashing. So first it will go through padding. So for message `a` asci value `61` will be send for padding which is nothing but `61` hex.

So after value `61` there will be `1` and followed by zeros and last 64 bits will be length of message. So as per little endian conventions, byte wise representation of `a` after padding will looks like below right?

```
512'h08000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008061
```

(MSB side last byte `08` is nothing but length of message `a` LSB side `61` is actual message then followed by `1` and zeros) as ripemd is little endian based.

Please correct me if I am wrong. Is my description correct? If not, how does RIPEMD160 pad the message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[RIPEMD-160](http://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/~bosselae/ripemd160.html) uses precisely the same padding and endianess convention as MD5.

Everything is little-endian, with the exception of the order of bits in bytes, which is kept big-endian. If the message is $n$-bit, it is appended a single bit at `1` and $511-((n+64)\bmod512)$ bit(s) at `0` , then the representation of $n$ on 64 bits. The resulting padded message is an integral number of 512-bit blocks, which are each considered 16 words of 32 bits.

Note: It follows that the padding bit at `1` corresponds to a byte mask with value $2^{7-(n\bmod 8)}$. The $n\bmod 8$ last message bit(s) are in the high-order bit(s) of that byte, which $7-(n\bmod 8)$ low-order bit(s) are 0.

---

Suppose the message is the one-character string "a", and that is coded in ASCII as the single byte 61<sub>h</sub> = 01100001<sub>b</sub> = 97.

That's the bitstring `01100001`. $n=8$, thus the padding is `1` followed by 439 `0` (with the first eight bits of that padding `10000000` corresponding to byte 80<sub>h</sub>), followed by the length $n=8$ represented as the bitstring `00001000 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000000 00000000 00000000 0000000` (with the first eight bits `00001000` corresponding to the byte 08<sub>h</sub>).

Showing this as a string of 64 bytes with bytes and 32-bit boundaries shown (and individual bytes shown in big-endian hexadecimal), the padded block is

```
61 80 00 00   00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00   08 00 00 00   00 00 00 00
```

Packing that into 32-bit words using little-endian convention (and individual 32-bit words shown in big-endian hexadecimal), we get

```
00008061      00000000      00000000      00000000
00000000      00000000      00000000      00000000
00000000      00000000      00000000      00000000
00000000      00000000      00000008      00000000
```

or in decimal `{ 32865, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0 }`.

---

Note: a former version of this answer did not take into account the exception to little-endianness in the conversion of bytes to/from bits, and used uppercase ASCII code in the example. I'm confident about the present revised version.

---

Simple demonstration and example output for the reference code rmd160

```
// Demonstration of rmd160 - public domain
// note: on machines with more than 32-bit unsigned long, rmd160.h requires a simple change
#include "rmd160.h" // at http://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/~bosselae/ripemd160/ps/AB-9601/rmd160.h
#define SIZEOFHASH  20      // size of the hash in bytes
#define SIZEOFBLOCK 64      // size of a block in bytes

// including the code simplifies compilation+linking into a tool
#include "rmd160.c" // at http://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/~bosselae/ripemd160/ps/AB-9601/rmd160.c

// hash a byte buffer in memory
void hashmd160(
    const byte  *iData,             // input
    size_t      iDataLength,        // size of input in bytes
    byte        oHash[SIZEOFHASH]   // result (must be allocated by caller)
    )
    {
    dword       vHash32[SIZEOFHASH%4==0 ? SIZEOFHASH/4 : -1 ];      // the hash, as 32-bit words
    dword       vBlock32[SIZEOFBLOCK%4==0 ? SIZEOFBLOCK/4 : -1 ];   // a block, as 32-bit words
    size_t      vb;
    int         vj;
    // start hashing
    MDinit(vHash32);
    // hash full blocks; needed only when iDataLength>=SIZEOFBLOCK
    for (vb = iDataLength/SIZEOFBLOCK; vb!=0; --vb)
        { // make a little-endian copy of SIZEOFBLOCK bytes from iData to vBlock32
        for (vj = 0; vj<SIZEOFBLOCK/4; ++vj, iData += 4)
            vBlock32[vj] = iData[0] | iData[1]<<8 | (dword)(iData[2] | iData[3]<<8)<<16;
        compress(vHash32,vBlock32);
        }
    // hash remaining bytes
    MDfinish(vHash32, (byte *)iData, iDataLength, iDataLength>>16>>16);
    // make a little-endian copy of SIZEOFHASH bytes from vHash32 to oHash
    for (vj = 0; vj<SIZEOFHASH; ++vj)
        oHash[vj] = (byte)(vHash32[vj>>2]>>((vj&3)<<3));
    }

// hash each argument, print its hash and the (quoted) argument
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
    byte    vHash[SIZEOFHASH];
    int     vj,va;
    for(va=1; va<argc; ++va) {
        hashmd160((const byte *)(argv[va]),strlen(argv[va]),vHash);
        for (vj = 0; vj<SIZEOFHASH; ++vj)
            printf("%02x",vHash[vj]);
        printf(" \"%s\"\n",argv[va]);
        }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

/* Example output
9c1185a5c5e9fc54612808977ee8f548b2258d31 ""
0bdc9d2d256b3ee9daae347be6f4dc835a467ffe "a"
8eb208f7e05d987a9b044a8e98c6b087f15a0bfc "abc"
5d0689ef49d2fae572b881b123a85ffa21595f36 "message digest"
f71c27109c692c1b56bbdceb5b9d2865b3708dbc "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
12a053384a9c0c88e405a06c27dcf49ada62eb2b "abcdbcdecdefdefgefghfghighijhijkijkljklmklmnlmnomnopnopq"
b0e20b6e3116640286ed3a87a5713079b21f5189 "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
9b752e45573d4b39f4dbd3323cab82bf63326bfb "12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
*/
```

Comment: Thanks @fgrieu.
 
Still i have bit confusion.

If we considering  big endianess, input message will be something like this

65800000...........0000000008

65 ="a" in hex     8000..... = 1 and zero pad          08= 8 bit length.

Because it is little endian it will order like this.

08000000...........0000008065

As in little endian byte wise reverse will occur not all bit exact reverse as you have mentioned in your answer.
please correct me

Comment: thanks @fgrieu. This gave me clear idea. Now I am trying to test my RIPEMD 160. I am using some test vectors and online hash converters. My results are not matching. So must be my hashing functions has some functional bug. So is there any test suite which gives round wise output of all constants ???. Like for SHA1,2 there are sites which gives output for each rounds. which makes debugging bit easier. Thanks in advance that helped a lot to me

Comment: @seeker: the page I link to links to a reference C implementation. It is easy to instrument to show intermediary results. I'm not aware of other source of intermediary results.

Comment: I tried using c codes from link you have provided. But I am not sure that implementation is correct. Because i tried giving some inputs for c code. But final hash results are not matching with expected standard results. Like i have given "a" as input but for which c code giving hash value as  508a6ccc545b32641fe7311048defe7cf599ada3. but the expected ripemd hash value for "a" is 0bdc9d2d256b3ee9daae347be6f4dc835a467ffe. so is that c implementation is correct?????

Comment: @seeker: I see no issue with the reference implementation; it works fine for me, with the (documented) issue is that it uses a non-portable definition of the 32-bit type `dword`. If the compiler barks, that should be changed from `unsigned long` to `uin32_t` from `<stdint.h>`, or just `unsigned` on many modern machines. Try to use that reference code from the simple main program that I posted.

Comment: Thanks you very much sir. That help me a lot in doing software implementation. Actually problem was same which you have mentioned. Changing unsigned long to unsigned int and kudos it's working totally fine. As I am hdl coder didn't work much on C, I couldn't get it easily. Now I can easily go back to debugging verilog hardware implementation of ripemd. Thanks again for your valuable time.